# How to easily show the equation behind ggplot's geom_smooth

Tags: r, ggplot2, equation

Is there any simple command to show the geom_smooth equation of a non-linear relationship? Something as simple as "show. equation". The equation has to be somewhere, I just want to call the equation used by default.

```
ggplot(dataset, aes(x=variablex, y=variabley)) + 
  geom_point()+
  geom_smooth()+
  theme_bw()
```

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the [documentation](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_smooth.html) for `geom_smooth` and `stat_smooth` you can see that it uses `stats::loess` for small data sets (1,000 observations) and `mgcv::gam` otherwise:

> For `method = NULL` the smoothing method is chosen based on the size of
> the largest group (across all panels). `stats::loess()` is used for less
> than 1,000 observations; otherwise `mgcv::gam()` is used with `formula = y ~ s(x, bs = "cs")` with `method = "REML"`. Somewhat anecdotally, loess
> gives a better appearance, but is (2) in memory, so does not work
> for larger datasets.

So if you want to use the model implied by the `geom_smooth` fit, you could just call the underlying method (e.g. `stats::loess(variabley ~ variablex, data = dataset)`) and then use the `predict` method to calculate values for new data.